# HTML| How to add a regular border in css to a div element? Border is stuck on top of website

Tags: html, css, border

How would I add a border around the div "border" class? within CSS, I tried doing it before but the border would just show as a straight line on the top of the site and nothing around the div contents. please help! I want there to be a border around the first image along with the h2, h3, menchies class, h4, and walgreens class.
Here is the HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Employment</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1> Joshua Eachus</h1>
<div class="border">
<img class="img" src="headshot.jpg" alt="Joshua Eachus">

<h2>Job Experience</h2>

<h3>Menchies</h3>

<p class="menchies"> Between January 2020-November 2020 I was a team member at menchies, 
I would mainly greet customers, help them around the store if needed and cash them out 
with the cash register when ready. I also am constantly busy 
making sure every topping and yogurt machine is filled up for the customers. 
I would usually be closing so I work 5 to 8 hour shifts every time. 
When closing I would put all the toppings away, clean the whole store 
completely and prep food for the next day.</p>

<h4>Walgreens</h4>

<p class="Walgreens"> I am currently working at Walgreens, which has been a great introduction into retail 
and has truly taught me many things. There is a diverse and large amount of tasks I do at Walgreens,
 one of the main tasks is running the photo department, where I print many kinds of photos, 
 create canvases and many more projects. Other tasks includes stocking, 
 outdating, cleaning duties and counting registers.</p>
</div>
<h5>Achievements</h5>

<img class="img2" src="ptk.jpg" alt="PTK">
<p class="ptk">I am a member of Phi Theta Kappa. Founded on November 19, 1918 Phi Theta Kappa is the world’s largest organization specifically 
devoted to recognizing the achievements of honor students at 2-year institutions. Currently, 
PTK has approximately 3 million members globally.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS Code:

```
html{background-color:white;}

h1{text-align:center;
   font-size:50px;}
    
h2{position:fixed;
   top:180px;
   left:475px;
   font-size:40px;}
   
h3{position:fixed;
   top:230px;
   left:365px;
   font-size:33px;}
   
h4{position:fixed;
   top:450px;
   left:365px;
   font-size:33px;} 
   
h5{position:fixed;
   top:130px;
   right:430px;
   font-size:33px;}


.img{height:470px; 
     width:320px;
     position:fixed; 
     top:220px; left:15px;}
     
.img2{width:500px; 
      height=100px;
      position:fixed; 
      top:250px; right:280px;}
      
.menchies{position:fixed;
         top:290px;
         left:350px;
         font-size:20px;
         width:30%;}
         
.Walgreens{position:fixed;
         top:520px;
         left:350px;
         font-size:20px;
         width:30%;}

.ptk{position:fixed;
     top:540px;
     right:250px;
     font-size:18px;
     width:30%;}
```

Comment: You have `fix` positioned all of your content-- this pulls it out of the normal document flow, which is why the wrapper isn't respecting its contents.  Generally speaking you want to avoid using `position: absolute` or `fixed` for general layout purposes-- they should be reserved for special cases.  If you are attempting to learn web development, a proper tutorial on how to properly apply CSS would be highly recommended.  If you're just trying to make a website, then this might be more work than you are anticipating, and you might consider SquareSpace or something. Good luck, and happy coding!

Comment: Just have a look at the code I have written below and try to understand how to make a proper layout :)

Answer (score 2):

## Stop using position fixed

You are using CSS to shoot yourself in the foot, stop it. Go watch some [Layout Land](https://www.youtube.com/c/layoutland) and take Kevin Powell's free [Conquering Responsive Layouts](https://courses.kevinpowell.co/conquering-responsive-layouts) course.

```css
/*
html {
  background-color: white; Background is already white
}
*/

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3rem;
  /* Use font sizes that respect the user setting */
}

body {
  max-width: 60ch;
  margin-inline: auto;
}

.border {
  border: 2px solid tomato;
}


/*
DO NOT POSITION FIX EVERYTHING
h2 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 180px;
  left: 475px;
  font-size: 40px;
}

h3 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 230px;
  left: 365px;
  font-size: 33px;
}

h4 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 450px;
  left: 365px;
  font-size: 33px;
}

h5 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 130px;
  right: 430px;
  font-size: 33px;
}

.img {
  height: 470px;
  width: 320px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 220px;
  left: 15px;
}

.img2 {
  width: 500px;
  height=100px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 250px;
  right: 280px;
}

.menchies {
  position: fixed;
  top: 290px;
  left: 350px;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 30%;
}

.Walgreens {
  position: fixed;
  top: 520px;
  left: 350px;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 30%;
}

.ptk {
  position: fixed;
  top: 540px;
  right: 250px;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 30%;
}
*/
```

```html
<h1> Joshua Eachus</h1>
<div class="border">
  <img class="img" src="headshot.jpg" alt="Portrait of Joshua Eachus">

  <h2>Job Experience</h2>

  <h3>Menchies</h3>

  <p class="menchies"> Between January 2020-November 2020 I was a team member at menchies, I would mainly greet customers, help them around the store if needed and cash them out with the cash register when ready. I also am constantly busy making sure every topping and yogurt
    machine is filled up for the customers. I would usually be closing so I work 5 to 8 hour shifts every time. When closing I would put all the toppings away, clean the whole store completely and prep food for the next day.</p>

  <h3>Walgreens</h3>

  <p class="Walgreens"> I am currently working at Walgreens, which has been a great introduction into retail and has truly taught me many things. There is a diverse and large amount of tasks I do at Walgreens, one of the main tasks is running the photo department, where I
    print many kinds of photos, create canvases and many more projects. Other tasks includes stocking, outdating, cleaning duties and counting registers.</p>
</div>
<h2>Achievements</h2>

<img class="img2" src="ptk.jpg" alt="PTK">
<p class="ptk">I am a member of Phi Theta Kappa. Founded on November 19, 1918 Phi Theta Kappa is the world’s largest organization specifically devoted to recognizing the achievements of honor students at 2-year institutions. Currently, PTK has approximately 3 million
  members globally.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I have rearranged your site layout! Just have a look at it and try to understand how to do it in proper way. Please click on full page when you run this in the Stack Overflow code snippet because this is not mobile friendly.

If you want to learn more about this, visit [W3Schools CSS Website Layout](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_website_layout.asp) tutorial or any other one which is related to this.

```css
h1{
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 5px;
}
h2{
    font-size: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
h3{
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 5px;
}
p{
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: justify;
}
.container{
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #ff00ff;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.section{
    padding: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.one{
    width: 20%;
}
.two{
    width: 35%;
}
.three{
    width: 35%;
}
img{
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Employment</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Joshua Eachus</h1>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="section one">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/VLV0qfv/Wood-Floor-Texture-Seamless.jpg" alt="Joshua Eachus">
        </div>
        <div class="section two">
            <h2>Job Experience</h2>
            <h3>Menchies</h3>
            <p class="menchies"> Between January 2020-November 2020 I was a team member at menchies,
            I would mainly greet customers, help them around the store if needed and cash them out with the cash register when ready. I also am constantly busy making sure every topping and yogurt machine is filled up for the customers. I would usually be closing so I work 5 to 8 hour shifts every time. When closing I would put all the toppings away, clean the whole store completely and prep food for the next day.</p>
            <h3>Walgreens</h3>
            <p class="Walgreens"> I am currently working at Walgreens, which has been a great introduction into retail and has truly taught me many things. There is a diverse and large amount of tasks I do at Walgreens, one of the main tasks is running the photo department, where I print many kinds of photos, create canvases and many more projects. Other tasks includes stocking, outdating, cleaning duties and counting registers.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="section three">
            <h3>Achievements</h3>
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/VLV0qfv/Wood-Floor-Texture-Seamless.jpg" alt="PTK" style="height: 200px;">
            <p>I am a member of Phi Theta Kappa. Founded on November 19, 1918 Phi Theta Kappa is the world’s largest organization specifically devoted to recognizing the achievements of honor students at 2-year institutions. Currently, PTK has approximately 3 million members globally.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Your problem is because you have used `position:fixed;` in almost every element. Please stop doing that and if you want to clarify whether your border is working properly or not, please give some padding to it and then you will see it works properly.

```css
.border{
    border: 1px solid #ff00ff;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="border">
</div>
```

If you can show what you actually need to make, I will be able to do it without using `position: fixed;` If you have a image of what you exactly need, just share it with us.

Thanks and best regards!